# JQuery can't find select options by text

Tags: jquery

I have a select element with 10 options . I am trying to select a specific option by its text. when I do -

```
$('#category_id option:last').text();
```

I get result as "Complete plant" but when I do -

```
$('#equipment_category_id option[text="Complete plant"]');
```

it returns a blank array.

Comment: `[]` is for matching attributes. So unless you have `<option text="Complete plant">` that won't match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **[`:contains()`](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)** which selects all elements that contain the specified text.

```
$('#equipment_category_id option:contains(Complete plant)')
```

---

or use **[`filter()`](https://api.jquery.com/filter/)** method for exact match

```
$('#equipment_category_id option').filter(function(){ return $(this).text() == 'Complete plant' })
```

Comment: @sajan : glad to help

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
var text = 'text';
$("##equipment_category_id option").filter(function() {
    return this.text == text; 
}).attr('selected', true);
```